# Map JSON if input field isnt currently 0

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

Ive just created a search and filtering input in React and have a bug where the JSON always maps the names of the suggest searches even if you dont search. I would like it so that the suggestions only appear if the user begins to type into the input field. I was wondering if this is possible by using an

```
if (variable.length != 0) {//Do something}
```

Heres my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const content = [
    {link: '/review/elden-ring', name: 'Elden\nRing'},
    {link: '/review/', name: 'defg'},
    {link: '/review/', name: 'ghij'},
    {link: '/review/', name: 'jklm'},]

export default function Search(props) {
    //For storing and setting search input
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    return (
        //Search input
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <form class="text-black ml-5 py-0.5 lg:py-0 flex border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md bg-white px-1">
                <input class="focus:outline-none" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" onChange={event => {setQuery(event.target.value)}}/>
                
                <div class="flex"> {/* Flex container to align the icon and bar */}
                    <button type="submit">
                        <svg class="fill-current h-auto w-4 " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"> {/* ! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. */}
                        <path d="M500.3 443.7l-119.7-119.7c27.22-40.41 40.65-90.9 33.46-144.7C401.8 87.79 326.8 13.32 235.2 1.723C99.01-15.51-15.51 99.01 1.724 235.2c11.6 91.64 86.08 166.7 177.6 178.9c53.8 7.189 104.3-6.236 144.7-33.46l119.7 119.7c15.62 15.62 40.95 15.62 56.57 0C515.9 484.7 515.9 459.3 500.3 443.7zM79.1 208c0-70.58 57.42-128 128-128s128 57.42 128 128c0 70.58-57.42 128-128 128S79.1 278.6 79.1 208z" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

            {/* Search Suggestions */}
            <div class="ml-5 px-0.5">
                
                {content.filter((content) => {
                    //If input return object
                    if (query == "") {
                        return content
                    }

                    //If any input characters much object characters return corresponding object
                    else if (content.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
                        return content
                    }

                })
                //Maps element based on the number of json objects
                .map((content) => {
                    return(
                        <div class="bg-white rounded-sm">
                            <Link to={content.link}><p>{content.name}</p></Link>
                        </div>
                    );
                })};
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Heres how the input currently looks

[image]

Heres how I want it too look

[image]

And heres how it looks when you start searching

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, you're having results even when user has not typed anything, so you could `useMemo` hook to calculate results that you'll be showing (This can help you with performance in a future too)

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    const results = useMemo(() => {
        if (!query) {
            return [];
        }

        return data.filter(item => item.name.toLowercase().includes(query.toLowercase()));
    }, [query])

    return <div onFocus={onFocus}>{results}</div>
}
```

Old approach (onFocus):

You can add a `onFocus` function that updates your state

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const onFocus = () => {
        const data = getNewData();
        setData(data);
    }

    return <div onFocus={onFocus}>{data}</div>
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how this works in the context of the code I gave.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Still no sorry Im new to React so i can understand very full unless you use the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's often useful to separate out functions to make things a little easier to debug.

1. I don't know where your data is coming from so in this example I'm passing it into the component as a prop. But I'm also immediately storing it in state.
2. The input still updates the `query` state
3. I have a new function that [`filters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the relevant data from the `data` state, and then [`maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) out the values from the name properties.
4. Finally, if the length of the filtered data is 0 show "No results", otherwise, call the `createJSX` function with the filtered data.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ arr }) {

    // So: I like to store data in state. At some
    // point I might want to switch to a different state
    // management system like Context, or Recoil, or Redux.
    // In this case I'm just passing in the data as a property
    // of the component, and then setting the data state with it
    const [data, setData] = useState(arr);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    // This does what your code already does - it
    // sets the query state to the value of the input
    // See: destructuring assignment in the footnotes
    function handleChange(e) {
      const { value } = e.target;
      setQuery(value);
    }

    // Here we're filtering out the data (just like your
    // code), and then `mapping` over the returned objects
    // to get an array of names (just like your code)
    function getFiltered(data) {
      return data.filter(obj => {
        const name = obj.name.toLowerCase();
        return name.includes(query.toLowerCase());
      }).map(obj => obj.name);
    }

    // Just creating some elements
    function createJSX(arr) {
      return arr.map(el => <li key={el}>{el}</li>);
    }
    
    // Getting the filtered elements
    const filtered = getFiltered(data);
    
    // And now we're using a ternary operator
    // to either display "No results" if there's nothing in
    // the filtered array, or the result of calling
    // `createJSX` with the filtered results
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {filtered.length
          ? <ul>{createJSX(filtered)}</ul>
          : <div>No results</div>
        }
       </div>
    );
}

const arr = [{name: 'abcd'}, {name: 'defg'}, {name: 'ghij'}, {name: 'jklm'}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example arr={arr} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Ternary/conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: The data is coming from the content array just below the imports.

Comment: That's fine. Was there something you didn't understand about the code I wrote? The principle is: hold your data in state, and then filter out the parts you need. @JoshHaywood. This was just a small example to show you how it might work.

Comment: Yeah im pretty new too React so a lot of that didnt make sense to me. Could you use it in terms of the code ive provided.

Comment: That's fine, Josh. We all started at the beginning. I'll annotate my code a little. I'm basically doing the same thing you are but approaching a slightly different way.

Comment: I'm not sure if that update was helpful. Basically I like to separate little functions out to do their own thing. It makes things easier to test. Give me a shout if you have any questions.